# Hypothesis space in AdaBoost or general Machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, classification, learning-theory

I was curious about the following: in most learning algorithms, when an algorithm is said to learn a concept class $C$ then the algorithm outputs a function from the  hypothesis space $H$ and often the complexity of the learning algorithm is stated in terms of the VC dimension of $H$. I was wondering, what is an assumption on $H$, for example, does it include all possible functions or does it only include $C$, is there any reference which talks about the properties of function in $H$ that I can assume? Say, for every $c\in C$, does there always exist an $h\in H$ for which $Pr_{x} [h(x)=c(x)]\geq 1-\varepsilon$ for every $\varepsilon>0$. Is this fair to assume?